# New Goodman 96% furnace install - E11 open roll out error

Tags: hvac

Furnace will run for about 15 minutes, then I get E11 open roll out error.  New install.  3" intake and exhaust transition to 4" immediately, used same pipes as previous furnace.  Furnace is pitched, so water will drain.  Tried intake gas pressure of 9 and 4, did not make a difference.  Gas pressure at Low and High is 3.5.  Tried higher and lower, no difference.  If I leave the cover off, it works fine.  Removed the plenum, no obstruction and plenty of air flow.  Looking at the furnace, the left side does get warmer.  Duct work has all been taped so no leaks.  Tried programming the fan to higher setting, did not make a difference. Swapped position of sensor, sensor on left looking at furnace always trips after 10 to 15 minutes.
I'm at a loss for what to do?

Comment: Complete sentence. Good communication. Self install? Call back the HVAC guy to fix. What size exhaust called for? Formatting. [Edit]

Answer (score 1):

OK, I fixed it.  I have a five wire thermostat.  The furnace is supposed to change from fan lo to fan high after a set period of time.  For some reason, mine is not.  I force it to go to fan high and everything works.  Now just need to understand why my single stage thermostat does not work.